# STUN UDP request packet trouble

Tags: java, c, udp, nat, stun

I am trying to use some globally available STUN servers so that they can tell me my NAT mapping in order to traverse the NAT with UDP. The servers are on this webpage:
http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7542
I tested them and they do ping. The problem is constructing a special STUN request packet,
because the servers don't respond on all incoming packets.

The packet structure for STUN protocol is not explained too good and I don't want to use any
libraries that already implement it. Are there some examples of either Java/C code or a carefully explained packet structure? I cannot find any information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STUN packet format is explained in perfect detail in [RFC 5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389).

If you want decent Java code for STUN - go take a look at [JSTUN](http://jstun.javawi.de/) sources. It's pretty easy to use their library and/or modify their code.

If you want to use my code, written in C++, you can peruse the sources of [Stuntman](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver). There's both a parser class (CStunReader) and a class to create STUN messages (CStunWriter).

Comment: Although I agree, that the RFC 5389 is detailing the STUN in great detail, after I tried to implement the header format, the conclusion at least from me was that it's one of the messiest wordings I have had to deal with. Using binary/hex notations in network/non-network orders in a mix ... It is very hard to follow and understand.

Comment: @Laazik - RFCs are often like that. Binary protocols are often hard.  And in the case of RFC 5389, it lazily refers back to RFC 3489 in some places. But if I can figure it out, then I think anyone with sufficient patience and time can too.

Comment: I know, I've been working with ETSI, ITU etc. standards and protocols for last 15 years and they are hard.

Nevertheless, statement of "Field must contain value 0xXYZ in network byte order." - has a lot of ambiguity in this sentence. 

It turns up it is already presented in the RFC in network byte order, I initially took the value and did change the ordering (according to my interpretation), which didn't work.

So I still think that it is really hard to interpret this specific chapter and could be done better :).